# GraphicsMagick installation error on FreeBSD

Tags: installation, freebsd, graphicsmagick

When trying to install Graphicsmagick binaries to FreeBSD using

```
sudo pkg install GraphicsMagick
```

via SSH shell, I get this error message:

> /usr/local/lib/libpkg.so.3: Undefined symbol "openat"

What is wrong?

Comment: What version is your FreeBSD system? The `openat` syscall was added in FreeBSD 8.0, while `pkg` was introduced in 9.1. Probably your system is too old be be supported by the current ports tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update FreeBSD.  You're trying to use a port too current for the system you are running.  You can either perform a binary upgrade, or you can update the source and build the kernel & world.

Comment: Ok thank you for that hint. I will check back on that.